# Jenkins: Get FOLDER Library by Name

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

in `/vars` for the folder I have `AaConfig.groovy`.

In the job's Groovy script I have:

```
#!groovy
@Library('globals') _

Class config = AaConfig
```

I can use `config` instead of `AaConfig` with no problems in subsequent code.

> *This is useful because I can call different configuration files: `AaConfig`, `BbConfig`, etc. without changing anything because i'm calling them through `config`*

So now I got greedy :-), and wanted to specify the config file externally:

```
#!groovy
@Library('globals') _

String configName = "AaConfig"
Class config = Class.forName(configName)
```

Now I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AaConfig
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load `AaConfig` class via reflection then you have to use the same classloader that your pipeline script uses. `Class.forName()` in this cases uses [`ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.15/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/reflection/ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.html) while Groovy CPS plugin uses [`CpsGroovyShell$CleanGroovyClassLoader`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsGroovyShell.java#L66).

Below you can find an example of loading class using pipeline current classloader:

```groovy
String configName = 'AaConfig'

Class config = this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(configName)
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Just had to remember to pass the `script` as a parameter as this was done in a global library...